# Not Passing Through Application Error When Controller Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use Application_Error() in global.asax to log bad URL's on a website and redirect to custom error landing page. The problem is why does the website not passing through application error when controller doesn't exist.

I tested the following URL's and everything passed through application error:

- http://localhost:11843/Account/randomtext
- http://localhost:11843/Home/randomtext/randomval

This one doesn't pass through application error and returns 404:

- http://localhost:11843/nonExistingController

Application error code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var requestTime = DateTime.Now;
     Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
     //log Request.Url.ToString()
}
```

RouteConfig.cs code:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Account",
    url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "Home/{action}/{test}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeBlank",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Is the HandleErrorAttribute registered as a global filter? Have you considered using ELMAH (which logs all exceptions by default)?

Comment: Yes, HandleErrorAttribute is added. I'll check ELMAH. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following to your `RouteConfig.cs` :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Some URLs will fail to be parsed and adding above will handle these cases. In your action `NotFound` of `ErrorController`, you can show the user your Custom Error page.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```